# How to have a SharePoint action invoke a feature in a WinForms application launched by Click-Once?

Tags: winforms, sharepoint, clickonce

We have a SharePoint site that our users have open all the time (type of dashboard for the business).  We have a WinForms application that listens on a specific port for when the user clicks a web part on the SharePoint site, we take the JSON in the WinForms, parse the request and launch a feature in the WinForms.  Essentially allowing a web site to launch a feature in a running WinForms app on the same client machine.

This worked great when we were running in XP.  When we moved to Windows 7 (with elevated UAC), this feature stopped working.  Since we launch the WinForms app via ClickOnce, and ClickOnce apps can't be Run As Administrator, our current code won't work.

We can't make the ClickOnce app Run As Administrator for all the reasons you see here on StackOverflow.

So my question is:  how can we invoke a feature in a ClickOnce deployed WinForms app when a user clicks on something in SharePoint site?  It is super easy to get the WinForms app to call a Sharepoint web service but I need to go the otherway.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a ClickOnce application by calling the deployment manifest URL. If you want to be able to call the app and have it do something specific, call the deployment manifest URL and pass query parameters to it, then have the application handle the query parameters.

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172242%28VS.80%29.aspx) shows you how to handle query parameters with ClickOnce applications.